# Openrave compatibility with ROS

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, openrave

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

I would like to install openrave and make it work together with ROS, but I am unsure of which versions of ROS are compatible. I would like to try Hydro, as it is the latest ROS version. Is it a good idea? Has somebody done it already? Should I install Fuerte instead for which I have seen that there is compatibility and even a package that integrates Openrave in ROS? My Ubuntu version is 12.04 (precise).

Thanks in advance.

Fran.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101076/openrave-compatibility-with-ros/) by [Fran](https://answers.ros.org/users/294/fran/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-11-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are some examples of ROS integration with OpenRave from Fuerte: http://wiki.ros.org/openrave

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0